# How is SQLite so fast when modifying huge files?

Tags: performance, sqlite

So, I've been playing around with a 2GB SQLite database file and I'm really curious as to how modifying the database data performs so well. If I insert, update or delete some data, the data is persisted to the database file in about 0.5s - into a 2GB file that's on a (mechanical) HDD!

I always thought that to insert a single byte into a file, you needed to move all the subsequent bytes, but my HDD has nowhere near the speed needed to achieve this in 0.5s with such a large file.

Anyone know how SQLite achieves this feat of black magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how it works. The [file format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html) is documented in detail, but to summarize, new rows usually are appended to a table, and in any case the pages in the database file can be arranged randomly. (The interesting thing is how the database manages to find and *read* the data.)

Most of that 0.5 s is transaction overhead (forcing the data to disk, and waiting for the writes to complete). You can reduce this by enabling [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html), or by [disabling the rollback journal completely](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode).

Comment: Cool, I think I get the rough idea: Insert rows at the end, when deleting just mark the range as free, updating just overwrites certain bytes but does not affect subsequent rows. Probably a huge oversimplification, though. I guess all databases have the same problem to solve and probably do so in a similar way.

Comment: Essentially, everything is [B-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree).